# Обрезаем картинку скриптом на PHP

Tags: скрипт, php, изображения

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
<?
// отрезаем от картинки часть, и сохраняем
function crop($crop = 'square',$percent = false) {
    $file_input = "img/fon.jpg"; // картинка на входе
    $file_output = "img/fon_plus.jpg"; // картинка на выходе
    //$crop = "square";
    //$percent = "false";
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
        $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png','jpg');
        $ext = $types[$type];
        if($ext){
            $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
            $img = $func($file_input);
        }
    if ($crop == 'square') {
        $min = $w_i;
        if ($w_i > $h_i) $min = $h_i;
        $w_o = $h_o = $min;
    } else {
        list($x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o) = $crop;
        if ($percent) {
            $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
            $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
            $x_o *= $w_i / 100;
            $y_o *= $h_i / 100;
        }
        if ($w_o < 0) $w_o += $w_i; $w_o -= $x_o;
        if ($h_o < 0) $h_o += $h_i; $h_o -= $y_o;
    }
    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
    imagecopy($img_o, $img, 0, 0, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o);
    if ($type == 2) {
        return imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
    } else {
        $func = 'image'.$ext;
        return $func($img_o,$file_output);
    }
}
// по ширине берем от 0% до 100%, по высоте от 99% до 100%    
crop(array(0, 99, 100, 100),true);
?>
```

Собственно, вот скрипт. Как видно в вызове функции, мы отрезаем 1% высоты, начиная с нижней части изображения. Есть ли возможность укоротить или упростить данный код?

Comment: @mixalef, я вот совсем не понял пост скриптум. Выражайтесь точнее

Comment: Сам хотел переделать скрипт, как описал. так вот не могу ни какими методами приблизиться к решению, даже на чуть чуть. P.S. - это с чего я начал. В принципе удалить это можно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось сложнее, без приведения к квадрату но меньше по коду.

```
<?php function crop($filein, $fileout, $percent = false, $box = array()) {
    list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($filein);
    $ext = array_values(array('','gif','jpeg','png','jpg'))[$type];

    if($ext){
        $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
        $imageIn = $func($filein);
    }
    $func = 'image'.$ext;
    list($cropStartX, $cropStartY, $cropWidth, $cropHeight) = $box;
    if ($percent) {
        $cropStartX *=(($cropWidth *= $width / 100)/$cropWidth);
        $cropStartY *=(($cropHeight *= $height / 100)/$cropHeight);
    }
    $cropWidth += ($cropWidth < 0)?$width:-$cropStartX;
    $cropHeight += ($cropHeight < 0)?$height:-$cropStartY;

    $imageOut = imagecreatetruecolor($cropWidth, $cropHeight);
    imagecopy($imageOut, $imageIn, 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $cropWidth, $cropHeight);
    return $func($imageOut,$fileout);
}

print_r(
crop('1.png', '2.png',true, array(0, 99, 100, 100))
);
?>
```